# How to replace regular text in Excel into HTML unordered list (for export to CSV)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, export-to-csv, worksheet-function

How can I convert a specific column in an Excel sheet to HTML unordered list? Make it go from this:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

to:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I've searched the web and can't find anything even remotely close to the solution.

Comment: do you want to alter the original? or just make a copy of the values in the new format? with the first, you'd need to use vba and the second you can just use a formula and a little bit of manual editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming data is in ColumnA, in another column:

```
="<li>"&A1&"</li>"
```

copied down to suit, add `<ul>` at the top, `</ul>` at the bottom, select the another column Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top and delete ColumnA.

Comment: that only adds <li>...</li> around the whole content of the cell, not around each line in the cell.

Comment: Variable. Anywhere from 1 to 10. And quite honestly, I can skip the whole <ul>...</ul> part and just focus on adding <li> tags, if that's easier.

Comment: BAM! That's it. Another related question to this - is there any way to remove/get rid of all the white space/extra blank lines after some of this content? As some of the entries have extra blank lines that result in blank <li></li> entries. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73383/discussion-between-crazy-serb-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 0):

This might not work, wrote it in notepad..
If you add this to a new module, you can use it like a formula, specifying the range you want to convert to a list.

eg: `=getUnorderedList(A1:A10)` - you wont be able to use `A:A` type references to use the entire column as its currently written.

```
Public Function getUnorderedList(ByRef Target As Range) As String
Dim Result As String: Result = ""
Dim Cell As Variant

    For Each Cell in Target.Cells
        Result = Result & "<li>" & Cell.Value & "</li>" & vbNewLine 
    Next Cell

    getUnorderedList = "<ul>" & vbNewLine & Result & "</ul>"
End Function
```